# Ionic 2: How to use ViewChild instead of app.getComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm migrating my ionic 2 app into RC version in which app.getComponent is removed.
In their github release notes, they said about using ViewChild, how do I properly use it?

Before(working before RC version):

```
openPage(page) {
  this.app.getComponent('leftMenu').close();   
  // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
  let nav = this.app.getComponent('nav');
  nav.setRoot(page.component);  
}
```

After:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  queries: {
   leftMenu: new ViewChild('leftMenu'),
   nav: new ViewChild('content')
  }
})

....

openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.leftmenu.close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
 }
```

I'm trying to get the 'leftMenu' component without any success. The error i get is

> browser_adapter.js:77 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'close' of undefined

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695386/ionic-2-getcomponent-alternative

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ah, thanks for pointing it out. But there are no answers too

Comment: No, it's just for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following how it's done in the [Conference App](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/app/app.js) (and changing it just a little bit to simplify the code):

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ionicBootstrap, ..., Platform, MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';
...

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  queries: {
    nav: new ViewChild('content')
  }
})
class ConferenceApp {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[...], [Platform], [MenuController]]
  }

  constructor(..., platform, menu) {
    this.menu = menu;

    // Call any initial plugins when ready
    platform.ready().then(() => {
       ...
    });

 openPage(page) {
     this.menu.close();
     this.nav.setRoot(page);    
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(ConferenceApp, [...], {
  // config
});
```

So as far as I know, you can use the instance of the **`MenuController`** to execute the `close()` method and hide the side menu.

If you need the TypeScript version of this code, just add a comment and I'll update the answer, didn't want to add it  to keep the answer short.

Comment: Hi, If lets say i wish to get element of 'leftMenu' , how do I do it?