# Ionic 2 getComponent alternative

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

Since getComponent is no longer available i have the next scenario.

Inside app.ts and app.html i have a menu component and a nav component.
Inside the nav component i am adding a page witch contain tabs. When clicking on the menu, which is part of the app component i want to be able to change tabs.

Originally it was easy by using:

this.app.getComponent('mytabs').select(3)
Now i understand that i need to use viewchild so i tried using both:

```
@ViewChild('mytabs') tabs:Tabs;
```

The ion-tab component has a #mytabs reference.

And

```
@ViewChild(Tabs) tabs:Tabs;
```

Both time the this.tabs var is undefined. My guess is that the component is not available when the app.ts component is initialized. What are my options here?

Here is my ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local: Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.7
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.29
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.16
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables queried by `@ViewChild()` and `@ViewChildren()` are not initialized before `ngAfterViewInit()` was called. If you refer to `tabs` in the constructor or `ngOnInit()` it will be `null`.

Comment: What are my options here since i cannot use bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Ionic. `@ViewChild()` can only query elements in the template of the current component. I don't know how your app component and your tabs component are related.